# Nonstandard characterization of compactness

Tags: real-analysis, nonstandard-analysis

I'm trying to write up notes for myself on nonstandard analysis, consulting outside resources as little as possible. I have stumbled upon what seems to be referred to as Robinson's characterization of compactness:

$X$ is compact iff $\forall z \in X^* \ \exists x \in X \ x \approx z$

(Here $X^*$ is the hyperreal extension of the set $X$, and $x \approx z$ means $x$ and $z$ differ by an infinitesimal amount)

I had no issues showing that nonstandard formulations of open, closed, and bounded sets were equivalent to standard definitions. From them it was straightforward to show that a set is compact in the nonstandard sense if and only if it is closed and bounded; then from Heine-Borel we get equivalence to compactness in the standard sense. This is fine, but I find it more satisfying to directly show that the nonstandard formulations are equivalent to the standard ones and only then use the nonstandard definitions to prove classic results. Part of the attraction for me of nonstandard analysis is the ease in which it can be used to prove some results, but it feels a bit like cheating if those results are then needed to show that the new definitions are correct.

I have been able to prove that if $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is compact then it is compact in the nonstandard sense without using Heine-Borel: We start with some hyperreal number $z$ which is not infinitesimally close to any element of $X$. Then we take the set of all open intervals whose extensions do not contain $z$, which is an open covering of $X$ by choice of $z$. By compactness, this has a finite subcovering, $\{U_1, \dots, U_n\}$. By transfer, $\{U_1^*, \dots, U_n^*\}$ covers $X^*$ and so we can conclude that $z \not\in X^*$. The result follows by contraposition. Looking around a bit, this seems to be a common argument.

The issue is in trying to reverse this argument. I can't see how to make it work. The bit of notes I've seen reference a saturation assumption on the nonstandard model in order to prove the other direction. Unless I'm mistaken, the proof via Heine-Borel doesn't need this assumption so it shouldn't be necessary. I'd like to try to finish the proof as much as possible myself, but I'm totally stuck. I'd greatly appreciate a hint.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! To answer this question, we'll need to know which foundational framework (e.g. superstructures) you're using to do nonstandard analysis. Btw, the notes you're reading are right in that proving Robinson compactness equivalent to open cover compactness for an *arbitrary* topological space $T$ *does* require saturation. But you're proving it for subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, so using specific properties of $\mathbb{R}$ (such as H-B) can substitute for some of it. But e.g. when you conclude that an unbounded set of reals has an infinite element, that's already using some saturation.

Comment: As I've constructed it in my notes $\mathbb{H}$ is given as the ultrapower $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} / U$, where $U$ is some nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$. I'm avoiding referencing the construction in any proofs beyond those of a few basic properties: e.g. the transfer principle between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{H}$ (with symbols for constants, functions, and subsets) and that $\mathbb{H}$ contains an infinitesimal element, so I could potentially construct them in a different way.

Comment: I looked it up again in the other notes, and you are correct that they are working over an arbitrary topological space when they discuss compactness. Does this mean that any proof I give of the equivalence between the standard and nonstandard notions of compactness (in $\mathbb{R}$) is going to *essentially* go through Heine-Borel or something equivalent?

P.S.: Could you elaborate on this: "But e.g. when you conclude that an unbounded set of reals has an infinite element, that's already using some saturation."? It seems like that would follow from transfer alone

Comment: It does not really mean that any proof of equivalence of these two notions in $\mathbb{R}$ definitely goes through Heine-Borel, merely that any such proof has to invoke *some* "special" property of $\mathbb{R}$ that is not shared by every topological space. E.g. in my answer, I use the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is Lindelöf. This allowed me to get my hands on a sequence, and "squeeze" some saturation out of the existence of an infinite element $\omega$.

Comment: As for your second (implicit) question, "It seems like that would follow from transfer alone", that is not the case. Consider $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}/K$ where $K$ is a *principal* ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$: you can regard this as a degenerate (not at all saturated) extension of $\mathbb{R}$. Transfer clearly holds (it just asserts the tautology that every formula true in $\mathbb{R}$ is true in $\mathbb{R}$), and yet there are no infinitesimals. Your non-principal ultrapower *is* countably saturated, *that's* why e.g. the intersection $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (0,n^{-1})$ is nonempty there.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I misspoke saying "transfer alone." I didn't think of the existence of an infinitesimal (and infinite element) itself as a consequence of saturation. Thanks for clearing that up for me! I'm rusty on model theory (this is partly why I'm compartmentalizing the construction as much as possible). I'll review that and then read through your answers again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a set $T \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with an open cover $\mathcal{W}$ that has no finite subcover. I will construct an $h \in \!~^\star T$ that is not infinitesimally close to any element of $T$.

Notice that since $T$ is second-countable, $\mathcal{W}$ definitely has a countable subcover $\mathcal{V}$. Enumerate the countable subcover as $V_0, V_1, V_2, \dots $ and notice that for every $x \in T$ we can find some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $x \in V_n$. However, since $\mathcal{V}$ has no finite subcover, $V_0 \cup V_1 \cup \dots \cup V_m$ always constitutes a *proper* subset of $T$ for every $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

This means that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we can find a $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $m < n$, $y \not\in V_m$. By Transfer, the same holds for $\star$-extensions. In particular, picking your favorite hyperinteger $\omega \in \!~^\star \mathbb{N} \setminus \mathbb{N}$, you can find a $h \in \!\!~^\star \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $m < \omega$, $h \not\in \!\!~^\star V_m$. Consequently, $h \not\in \!\!~^\star V_n$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

If there was some $h' \in T$ infinitesimally close to $h$, then $h'$ would belong to one of the sets $V_n$, i.e. we'd have $h' \in \!\!~^\star V_n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. But $V_n$ is open, so then $h \in \!\!~^\star V_n$ would follow, a contradiction.

Taking contrapositives, we get that if every element of $\!~^\star T$ is infinitesimally close to some element of $T$, then every open cover of $T$ has a finite subcover.

Comment: Thanks for the proof! I wrote it up myself to make sure I followed correctly. My only concern is applying transfer to the statement "for all $m < n$, $y \not\in {V_m}$." To make this rigorous, I just think of the set $V = \{ (x, n) \mid x \in V_n\}$, and now I am really saying for all $m < n$, $(y, m) \not\in {V}$, correct? If so, this is similar to what I was attempting, but this use of second-countability + transfer is definitely the crucial step that I missed. Thanks so much!

Comment: Indeed, that's how you can see that Transfer applies to the statement in question. Best of luck with writing up your notes!

Answer (score 0):

$
\newcommand\ext[1]{{}^{*}\!#1}
\newcommand\std[1]{{}^\sigma\!#1}
\newcommand\Pfin{\mathcal P_{\mathrm{fin}}}
$

*Nonstandard Analysis: Theory and Applications* (1997) by Arkeryd, Cutland, and Henson, Proposition 7.4 (paraphrased):

- Assume a $\kappa$-saturated nonstandard extension. For any internal set $a$ and any (possibly external) $A \subseteq a$, if $|A| < \kappa$ then $A \subseteq b \subseteq a$ for some hyperfinite $b$.

In particular, what we want are for the *standard* elements of $a$ to be contained in a hyperfinite set; if this is true for all $a$, then the nonstandard extension is called an *enlargement*. In any case, the point is that in an extension which is saturated enough the following argument goes through.

---

Let $(X, T)$ be a topological space, and denote the nonstandard extension of e.g. $X$ by $\ext X$. We identity $X$ as a subset of $\ext X$. For any standard set $B$ and $A \subseteq \ext B$, we write
$$
  \std A = \{\ext x \;:\; \ext x \in A\text{ and }x \in B\},
$$
i.e. $\std A$ is the set of standard elements of $A$. The *monad* $\mu(x)$ of $x \in \ext X$ is
$$
  \mu(x) = \bigcap\{\ext U \;:\; U \in T\text{ and }x \in \ext U\},
$$
and we say $x \simeq y$ if $x \in \mu(y)$. Then $S \subseteq X$ is *nonstandard compact* if for all $x \in \ext S$ there is $y \in X$ such that $x \simeq y$, i.e. every element of $\ext S$ is nearstandard.

Now supposing $S \subseteq X$ is nonstandard compact, we wish that for every open cover $C$ of $S$ there is a finite subcover. Well, there is hyperfinite $H$ such that $\std C \subseteq H \subseteq \ext C$. If $x \in \ext S$, then by nonstandard compactness there is some $y \in S$ such that $x \simeq y$; but there is $c \in C$ such that $y \in c$, so $x \in \ext c \in \std C \subseteq H$. So $H$ covers $\ext S$. Thus
$$
  \exists H \in \ext\Pfin(C).\; \forall x \in \ext S.\; \exists h \in H.\; x \in h
$$
where $\Pfin(C)$ is the set of all finite subsets of $C$. By transfer,
$$
  \exists H' \in \Pfin(C).\; \forall x \in S.\; \exists h \in H.\; x \in h
$$
and $H'$ is a finite subcover of $C$.

---

The intuition behind this argument is sort of the following. Nonstandard compactness is a direct generalization of *finiteness*: a nonstandard set $A$ is finite iff
$$
  \forall x \in A.\; \exists y \in \std A.\; x = y,
$$
and it is nonstandard compact iff
$$
  \forall x \in A.\; \exists y \in \std A.\; x \simeq y.
$$
So in a sense if we "quotient" by $\simeq$, i.e. consider $\{\mu(y) \;:\; y \in \std A\}$, this set is "basically" finite and covers $A$; we just have to make a few adjustments to turn it into an *internal* set, and doing that we get $H$.

Comment: I do like the intuition about compactness being a generalization of finiteness. I had also noticed that formulation of finiteness. I had been trying to use it to help guide my proof, but to no avail.